# Jmeter Regular expression to capture default date value only incase of date value is null

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need a regular expression to capture default date value in case of date is null.

Regular expression to capture the date value in case of positive scenario:
when value is found no issue in the below case.

1.name="customer.BirthDay" class="date-picker2" value="2/2/1980" placeholder="M/d/yyyy"

when value is `null`, I need to capture some default value -1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  from regular expression, otherwise exception coming from application-Exception Message:

```
Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. Path 'BirthDa
```

2.name="customer.BirthDay" class="date-picker2" value="" placeholder="M/d/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the value in [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)'s `Default Value` field

> **Default Value**
>   If the regular expression does not match, then the reference variable will be set to the default value

Comment: regular expression matching but i am getting null value (when no value exist for date) , if there is a null value then only set the default value, how can i resolve this.

Comment: @Kumar exclude null in your regular expression

Comment: Thanks..here is my regex to get date value, how to exclude null here.. class="date-picker2" value="(.*?)"

Comment: @Kumar something like `class="date-picker2" value="[^null]+"`